# "I'm a student and I work at Burger King" or "I'm a student and work at Burger King"?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

Is is necessary to use the Subject Pronoun in the sentence below?

> I'm a student and **I** work at Burger King.

or

> I'm a student and work at Burger King.

Which one is correct according to the English grammar and what does it demand in cases like this?

Comment: Either is "correct".  Normally the first would be preferred, but there are contexts where the second would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with either. However, the first is generally preferred because the second implies a connection between the two things that really isn't present. Repeating "I" helps to separate the two pieces of information to avoid that unwanted implication.